# Attach a fragment to an activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, viewpagerindicator

My older version of an Android app was using 4 different activities (FirstActivity => FourthActivity, with the corresponding xml activity_first => activity_fourth), and the app can switch back and forth between those using `Intent`. Recently I wanted to change the user interface to use a `ViewPagerIndicator`. I have implemented 4 fragments like this:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first, null);
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I migrate all the business code from FirstActivity to FirstFragment? Do I just need to find the equivalents of onCreate, onDestroy, onStart... and copy/paste the code (adding getActivity(), getView() where appropriate)? Is there any easy way to attach the fragment to an activity to avoid doing so?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) website to be helpful with learning fragments. Also check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for the lifecycle of a fragment. A fragment has the same onCreate, onResume, onStop, etc. as an Activity but it also has more.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it is to migrate the code you had in your individual activities under `onCreate()` to `onActivityCreated()` in the new fragments. You then add the fragments to your activity using a fragment transaction in the `onCreate()` method of your supporting activity. The android docs give a pretty good walk through of how to do this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), complete with sample code. In case there's some confusion you're going to do the following in your underlying activity:

Get a new `FragmentManager`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Create a new instance of your fragment

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
```

Add that fragment to your `FragmentManager`

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

There are a number of different ways to use fragments - like in a `ViewPager` or `ViewSwitcher` that require a different implemenation but this sounds like it address what you're trying to do.